# Exporting a dataframe into an image

Tags: python, dataframe, image

Im currently trying to export a dataframe as a png file. Up until a few days ago, i was able to do this successfully using the dataframe_image module, using the dfi.export() function. Now it returns the error: `SyntaxError: not a PNG file`
This is the function im currently using. How can I fix this?

```
def imprimir_fig():
                        fig = pd.DataFrame(out)
                        pd.set_option('display.colheader_justify', 'center')
                        fig.columns=['Tipo','Valorizada']
                        fig= fig.style.hide_index()
                        fig= fig.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
                        fig= fig.set_table_styles([dict(selector = 'th', props=[('text-align', 'center')])])
                        dfi.export(fig, f'{dirG}\\moneda {comitente}.png')
                        return(fig)
                    imprimir_fig()
```

I tried using other functions of dfi but it seems it does not work anymore, does anyone have this similar issue?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it using an extra argument in the dfi.export() function:

```
dfi.export(fig, f'{dirG}\\compo {comitente}-{i}.png',table_conversion = 'matplotlib')
```